# Consulta SQL Mostra todos os registro

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma aplicao que deve mostrar em um dbgrid somente o id que seja igual a ordem de servico e que tenha o mesmo id em outra tabela:

A `ID_OrdemServico` vem da tabela `ordem_servico` por chave estrangeira para `pecas_ordem_servico`, gostaria de mostrar as peças usadas somente aonde os IDs fossem iguais

abaixo o codigo que no momento mostra todos os registros:

```
select * from pecas_ordem_servico 
where pecas_ordem_servico.id_OrdemServico = Id_OrdemServico
```

Comment: Opa, fiquei confuso com os nomes/ids das tabelas, mas tenta ai: select *
  from pecas_ordem_servico
 where pecas_ordem_servico.ID_OrdemServico = ordem_servico.ID_OrdemServico, to no celular hahaha se não funcionar avisa q revemos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que sua variável `Id_OrdemServico` tem o mesmo nome da coluna na tabela `pecas_ordem_servico`

Então o banco de dados está entendendo que o seu SQL é assim:

```
select * from pecas_ordem_servico 
where pecas_ordem_servico.id_OrdemServico = pecas_ordem_servico.id_OrdemServico
```

Então ele sempre retorna tudo, porque o valor da coluna `id_OrdemServico` sempre é igual a coluna `id_OrdemServico`. Entendeu?

Muda o nome da variável para `id_OrdemSer` e faz o SQL assim:

```
select * from pecas_ordem_servico  where pecas_ordem_servico.id_OrdemServico = id_OrdemSer
```

Vai funcionar como você quer.

Comment: negativo, alterei o nome para somente ID e apresenta essa mensagem

Comment: O identificador de várias partes "ordem_servico.ID" não pôde ser associado.

Comment: Você tem q alter a variável não a coluna, vc alterou a coluna e e ta dizendo que a coluna ID não na tabela ordem_servico não existe... E não existe mesmo

Comment: select * from pecas_ordem_servico 
where pecas_ordem_servico.id_OrdemServico = :Id_OrdemServico

Comment: o X da questão foi deixar um espaço após o final, agradeço a todos.

Comment: Nesse sql do comentário vc colocou um : na frente da variável, aí sim ele identifica como variável e não como a coluna, um espaço no final de um comando SQL não muda nada em banco nenhum, mas que bom q resolveu :)